# What is this door for?

Tags: glitch-2011

I found this door, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Nothing in Glitch (thus far) has been without purpose, what's this door for?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the one-way exit from [Martleby Hare](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Martleby_Hare), a street in Groddle Heights*, which can be accessed from Rookthills Lays with a Green-White circle key. There's a similar one-way exit for [Vicar's Peak](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Vicar%27s_Peak) located at [Mossystep](http://www.glitch.com/locations/LCR15ST40FM1M1I/) in Groddle Forest.

<sub>* The wiki is wrong in stating that both Martleby and Vicar's Peak are Seam Streets. They're actually part of Groddle Heights.</sub>